# Curses giving Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, curses

I am just writing a simple `stdscr.clear()` statement and it is giving segmentation fault.
I even tried to `try` and `except` every statement but still it didn't work.

```
from __future__ import division
import curses
from curses import wrapper
def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.refresh()
wrapper(main)
```

Comment: There's not enough information to guess what is amiss with your configuration.